# Rendering/displaying a navigation path with renderables in ARCore?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, arcore, sceneform

I am currently developing an indoor augmented reality navigation android application and I am struggling using Google ARCore with Sceneform to create a navigation path from my current location to the destination (my question is about rendering and displaying, I already have my location necessities sorted out).

If someone could describe to me conceptually, or with code, a good strategy to iteratively render an `arrowRenderable` at different positions I would be very appreciative (for example, do I use Poses, setWorldPosition(), setLocalPosition(), etc...). I can convert (lat,long) to camera space as well so I am really looking to understand ARCore rendering better.

Thank you in advance and please let me know if you would like additional information.

**EDIT:**

In regards to my implementation, I am using IndoorAtlas to handle my indoor positioning. The IndoorAtlas Android SDK comes with a wayfinding capability that creates routes from your current location to a destination (this is loaded in from a previously set wayfinding graph through IndoorAtlas online toolset). These routes are composed of legs that have a beginning and ending (lat,long) coordinates. What I am trying to do is render objects in AR iteratively along the ending (lat,long) coordinates.

Here is an example of one implementation I tried:

```
public void createNavigationPath() {
        // loop through the wayfinding route
        for (IARoutingLeg leg : mCurrentRoute) {

            // current loc
            Location currentLoc = new Location("Current Location");
            currentLoc.setLatitude(mLocation.latitude);
            currentLoc.setLongitude(mLocation.latitude);

            // end of wayfinding route segment
            Location legEnd = new Location("Leg End");
            legEnd.setLatitude(leg.getEnd().getLatitude());
            legEnd.setLongitude(leg.getEnd().getLongitude());

            // conversion from (lat,long) to camera space
            // conversion implementation credit:  
            // https://github.com/dat-ng/ar-location-based-android
            float[] currentLocationInECEF = WSG84toECEF(currentLoc);
            float[] pointInECEF = WSG84toECEF(legEnd);
            float[] pointInENU = ECEFtoENU(currentLoc, currentLocationInECEF, pointInECEF);

            float[] cameraCoordinateVector = new float[4];

            Matrix.multiplyMV(cameraCoordinateVector, 0, mRotatedProjectionMatrix, 0, pointInENU, 0);

            Frame frame = arFragment.getArSceneView().getArFrame();

            // cameraCoordinateVector[2] is z, that always less than 0 to display on right position
            // if z > 0, the point will display on the opposite
            if (cameraCoordinateVector[2] < 0) {
                float x = (0.5f + cameraCoordinateVector[0] / cameraCoordinateVector[3]) * arFragment.getArSceneView().getWidth();
                float y = (0.5f - cameraCoordinateVector[1] / cameraCoordinateVector[3]) * arFragment.getArSceneView().getHeight();

                // Pose pose = new Pose(new float[]{x,y,cameraCoordinateVector[2]}, new float[]{0,0,0});

                Anchor anchor = arFragment.getArSceneView().getSession().createAnchor(frame.getCamera().getPose().compose(Pose.makeTranslation(x,y,cameraCoordinateVector[2])).extractTranslation());
                AnchorNode anchorNode = new AnchorNode(anchor);

                Node tempNode = new Node();
                tempNode.setParent(anchorNode);
                tempNode.setRenderable(arrowRenderable);

                Log.d(TAG, "Render Completed");
            }
        }
    }
```

Alternatively, I have also tried to use some AR Geolocation SDKs like https://github.com/appoly/ARCore-Location but it was too inaccurate while moving. I have not tried the Wikitude SDK yet.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We will be able to help you better with some more context and details about your implementation, what you've already tried, and what isn't working. See the [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for asking a question effectively.

Comment: @J.Blackadar Thank you for your advice, I have edited my original question to try and add some more context to what I am asking.

Comment: wikitude worked really well in the demo that I tried but of course it's a paid solution. I had similar unsatisfactory results with ARCore-Location and haven't found a suitable open source solution yet